# error:> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "mode" argument must be integer. Received type function ([Function (anonymous)])

Tags: node.js

Help me to fix the issue am facing with node 14 (also tried with node 16/18) in release pipeline.

error:> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "mode" argument must be integer. Received type function ([Function (anonymous)])

**Existing code:**

```
console.log(
    '    :: INFO => Copying CF Update Stack File to GCDeploy Folder...'
);
fs.copyFileSync(
    serviceDir +
        '/' +
        slsFolder +
        sls_env +
        '/cloudformation-template-update-stack.json',
    serviceDir + '/gcdeploy/cloudformation-template-update-stack.json',
    (err) => {
        if (err) {
            _errorCount++;
            _errorsOccurred = true;
            throw err;
        }
    }
);
console.log('    :: INFO => Complete\n\n');
```

**Tried below modification but no luck**

```
const fs = require('fs');
console.log('    :: INFO => Copying CF Update Stack File to GCDeploy Folder...');
const sourceFilePath = serviceDir + '/' + slsFolder + sls_env + '/cloudformation-template-update-stack.json';
const destinationFilePath = serviceDir + '/gcdeploy/cloudformation-template-update-stack.json';

try {
  fs.copyFileSync(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath);
  // Set desired permissions on the copied file (e.g., 755)
  fs.chmodSync(destinationFilePath, 0o755);
  console.log('    :: INFO => Complete\n\n');
} catch (err) {
  _errorCount++;
  _errorsOccurred = true;
  console.error('Error copying CF Update Stack File:', err);
}
```

While running release pipeline to deploy the code